# Cloud 9 ide post data to page not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am developing a small node.js application using express on Cloud 9 ide.

I have a static index.html page and some routes defined. One of the routes is a post

```
app.post('/getJson', function (req, res) {
    jsonData = fetchData(req.body.selectpicker);
    res.render('index.html', '<p>tttt</p>');
});
```

As jade is not supported i just want to pass some html to the static page. Currently using

```
res.render('index.html', '<p>tttt</p>');
```

How can I render the html on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render()` function of the response renders a view and returns the HTML. If you want to render pages, you need a rendering engine such as EJS or Jade. If you're using either of those rendering engines, you can pass the HTML like so:

```
res.render('index.html, {
  html: '<p>tttt</p>'
});
```

Since Jade isn't supported (may I ask why?), this is how you'd insert the HTML fragment in EJS.

```
<p><%=: html %></p>
```

Comment: Dont think Cloud 9 ide has provided support for Jade yet. EJS is supported. So will give the above a go cheers

Comment: Do you add the ejs nect to the object html? res.render('index.html, {
  html: '<p><%=: html %></p>'
});

Comment: In the code example, I passed `<p>tttt</p>` to the document as variable `html`. So if I use `<%=: html %>` in my HTML document, it will be rendered as `<p>tttt</p>`. Aside from that, Cloud9 does indeed support Jade. It supports pretty much any Node module, because there is NPM access.